# Resend previous request in webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Is there any chance how I can resend the previous request if I got bad response. I.e. use case is the following:

- I'm clicking a button that does POST request
- I'm getting 502,503,504 error and I want to redo previous request

The thing is that whole process takes 5 continuous steps and only first is GET, others are not.

In common browser I can do it using `F5` key.

I know how do it with HTTP request, but is there a chance to redo this using webbrowser?

Comment: You could call the refresh-method

Comment: Doesn't it just refresh the current page using GET method?

Comment: Not if your last request was a POST

Comment: Thanks. That helped. But Can i dissmiss webbrowser dialog to "Retry" or "Cancel" the request? Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655525/accept-native-dialog-in-webbrowser