# Accept native dialog in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have the following code

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (current_state == "request_4")
    {
        webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true));
        webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)));
        InjectAlertBlocker();
    }
}
private void InjectAlertBlocker()
{
    HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
    IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
    string alertBlocker = "window.alert = function () { }";
    element.text = alertBlocker;
    head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
}
```

The refresh of the request I'm doing is POST request so WebBrowser instance is asking me all the the time if I want to "Retry" the request or not by showing Dialog window. How can I accept it or not show at all?

Suppressing errors or `InjectAlertBlocker()` doesn't help to do the trick.

I did not really understand http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31163/Suppressing-Hosted-WebBrowser-Control-Dialogs this approach.

I appreciate if anyone can explain how to use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

That code did the trick, however I still don't like it because it takes focus from current window I'm working with.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lp1, string lp2);
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static  extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
private void request_refresh()
{
    WebBrowserReadyState state1 = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete;
    webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true));
    webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)));
    while (state1 != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 10;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs exc)
{
    try
    {
        var handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        handle = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, handle, "#32770", "Web-browser");
        if (!handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (SetForegroundWindow(handle))
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                aTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```